# reduce function giving "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reshape a JSON object in javascript using the reduce function.

As i understand, each time a new property is added to an object in javascript, it must be declared like `ac['new_object'] = {};`.  I'm doing this, so i don't understand why I'm seeing the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined`

Reproducible example:

```
let field_list = [
    {
        "key": "id",
        "val": {
            "boost": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "title",
        "val": {
            "boost": 4
        }
    }
]

field_list.reduce(function(ac, cu){
    ac[cu.key] = {}
    ac[cu.key] = cu.val
}, {})
```

How can i correctly reduce this JSON object?  What was my error here?

Target format:

```
{
    tales: {
        foo: {"id": 2},
        bar: {"title": 1},
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Did you mean to use `forEach`? `reduce` is for accumulating the result of a function, but your function has no result.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?  The question seems pretty concise with a reproducible example and expected output- how could i improve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't forget to return the accumulator object at the end of the function:

```
field_list.reduce(function(ac, cu){
  ac[cu.key] = {}
  ac[cu.key] = cu.val
  return ac; // <---- added return statement
}, {})
```

Without that, `undefined` will be implicitly returned, and so the next iteration of the loop will have `ac` equal to `undefined`

Comment: I've literally spent an hour scratching my head about that- thank you

Comment: @User632716 This is not the intended use for `reduce`. You really just want `forEach`. `reduce` is for doing something where the value returned is a combination of the previous value (`ac`) and the current value (`cu`). For example, totaling up all the elements in a vector. But here, you're just returning the previous value (`ac`) over and over again.

Comment: @RaymondChen sequentially building up an object is a perfectly valid use of reduce.

Comment: @RaymondChen I doubted this, but thanks for making me do my homework, seems that `for` loops are fastest: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Comment: @RaymondChen "you're just returning the previous value (ac) over and over again" with regard to this, i'm adding parameters to the same object

Comment: @User632716 Yes, you are modifying the object, but you are just returning it as the value to be used by the next iteration. You can just capture it in the lambda instead of explicitly passing it around.